# Rails Assets: Load order

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline

I am attempting to use a package called angular-dragula which is available through bower as well as a gem.  I need the package to load **after** the DOM loads, in the body (not the head), but when I include the file in `application.js` with `//=require angular-dragula` it loads before the DOM, and results in an error.

Is there a way to control this?  When I try to include it in the `.html` with `<script src="bower_components/angular-dragula/angular-dragula.js"></script>`, I get a 404 error.

https://github.com/bevacqua/angular-dragula

Comment: Why do you think you need to load it after DOM? This file only includes angular directives AFAIK which are not invoked until angular boots.

Answer (score 0):

In the body of `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, add the following:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "angular-dragula" %>
```